# How to change a negative number to positive?

Tags: javascript

How to make a negative number to be positive (ie. -25 to be 25) in JavaScript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a negative number to a positive one in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652104/convert-a-negative-number-to-a-positive-one-in-javascript)

Answer (score 7):

There are various ways:

```
var m, n = -25;
m = -1 * n;
m = -n;
m = Math.abs(n);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var n= -25;
var m= -1 * n;
```

Answer (score 1):

use Math.abs function