# Convert a negative number to a positive one in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is there a math function in JavaScript that converts numbers to positive value?

Answer (score 1057, accepted):

You could use this...

```
Math.abs(x)
```

[`Math​.abs()` | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs)

Comment: You might want to even consider ~x+1. It's pretty quick, but not clear as to what it's doing. WHipped this up to show the difference: http://jsperf.com/absolute-int

Comment: @omgaz They aren't the same... `var x = -100; ~x+1 === 100` but `var x = 100; ~x+1 === -100`. `Math.abs` always makes it a positive whilst taking the ones complement simply inverts the sign.

Comment: You might want to even consider -x. It's pretty quick!

Answer (score 122):

What about `x *= -1`? I like its simplicity.

Comment: While this is simple, it makes the assumption that the number will always be negative. If the use case is such, then its awesome. Otherwise, I'd advise caution.

Comment: I disagree @myusuf. Any number that is `x` will be flipped. If `x = 23` and is shoved into that equation, `x` will then equal `-23`.  In the words of Mr. Escalante, "A positive times a negative equals a negative. A negative times a negative equals a positive." ... "How do I reach these kiiiiiiids?!"

Comment: Exactly @Shane yesterday. If `x=23`, then it'll become -23. As the question goes, 'Convert a negative number to a positive number in JS', but the above will flip any number, be it positive or negative.

Comment: Understood. My interpretation of your comment was in context of flipping the number and not making `x` always positive. My apologies @myusuf.

Comment: With this solution, if the number is 0 it will become -0

Comment: just remind that this solution doesn't apply for Float numbers, it only gets the decimal part

Comment: Nice solution, combined with a simple check it make the perfect combo. Thank you!

Answer (score 77):

I know this is a bit late, but for people struggling with this, you can use the following functions:

- **Turn any number positive**

  ```
  let x =  54;
  let y = -54;
  let resultx =  Math.abs(x); //  54
  let resulty =  Math.abs(y); //  54
  ```
- **Turn any number negative**

  ```
  let x =  54;
  let y = -54;
  let resultx = -Math.abs(x); // -54
  let resulty = -Math.abs(y); // -54
  ```
- **Invert any number**

  ```
  let x =  54;
  let y = -54;
  let resultx = -(x);         // -54
  let resulty = -(y);         //  54
  ```

Comment: invert any number was ingenious, thank you!

Answer (score 47):

`Math.abs(x)` or if you are **certain** the value is negative before the conversion just prepend a regular minus sign: `x = -x`.

Answer (score 30):

The minus sign (-) can convert positive numbers to negative numbers and negative numbers to positive numbers. `x=-y` is visual sugar for `x=(y*-1)`.

```
var y = -100;
var x =- y;
```

Answer (score 21):

```
unsigned_value = Math.abs(signed_value);
```

Answer (score 15):

```
var posNum = (num < 0) ? num * -1 : num; // if num is negative multiple by negative one ...
```

I find this solution easy to understand.

Answer (score 8):

If you'd like to write interesting code that nobody else can ever update, try this:

~--x

Comment: This won't work with floating points though... and the value of x changes too.

Comment: I guess if you can't change x:
~--x;++x

Comment: Kyle, the `~` operator does convert the number to a 32 bit integer. If you have a float as input, it gets hosed.

Answer (score 8):

Multiplying by (-1) is the fastest way to convert negative number to positive. But you have to be careful not to convert my mistake a positive number to negative! So additional check is needed...

Then Math.abs, Math.floor and parseInt is the slowest.

[image]

https://jsperf.com/test-parseint-and-math-floor-and-mathabs/1

Comment: Some of us forget how useful basic math can be in such cases.  Thanks for reminding me of such simplicity.

Answer (score 7):

Negative to positive

```
var X = -10 ;
var number = Math.abs(X);     //result 10
```

Positive to negative

```
var X = 10 ;
var number = (X)*(-1);       //result -10
```

Comment: I see what you want to show but the way you put it is confusing. Maybe you should state:
to positive: use abs, to negative: abs(x) * -1. This way you don't imply what the former X sign is.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the number to always be positive no matter what you can do this.

```
function toPositive(n){
    if(n < 0){
        n = n * -1;
    }
    return n;
}
var a = toPositive(2);  // 2
var b = toPositive(-2); // 2
```

You could also try this, but i don't recommended it:

```
function makePositive(n){
    return Number((n*-n).toString().replace('-','')); 
}
var a = makePositive(2);  // 2
var b = makePositive(-2); // 2
```

The problem with this is that you could be changing the number to negative, then converting to string and removing the **-** from the string, then converting back to int. Which I would guess would take more processing then just using the other function.

I have tested this in php and the first function is faster, but sometimes JS does some crazy things, so I can't say for sure.

Comment: The second example outputs the power of the input number. `n*-n` should be `n*-1`. I'd remove the example altogether, though, since the type conversions and method call are very inefficient compared to the simplicity of the first example. Even JS's quirkiness cannot possibly help here

Answer (score 2):

I did something like this myself.

```
num<0?num*=-1:'';
```

It checks if the number is negative and if it is, multiply with -1
This does return a value, its up to you if you capture it. In case you want to assign it to something, you should probably do something like:

```
var out = num<0?num*=-1:num; //I think someone already mentioned this variant.
```

But it really depends what your goal is. For me it was simple, make it positive if negative, else do nothing. Hence the '' in the code.
In this case i used tertiary operator cause I wanted to, it could very well be:

```
if(num<0)num*=-1;
```

I saw the bitwise solution here and wanted to comment on that one too.

```
~--num; //Drawback for this is that num original value will be reduced by 1
```

This soultion is very fancy in my opinion, we could rewrite it like this:

```
~(num = num-1);
```

In simple terms, we take the negative number, take one away from it and then bitwise invert it. If we had bitwise inverted it normally we would get a value 1 too small.
You can also do this:

```
~num+1; //Wont change the actual num value, merely returns the new value
```

That will do the same but will invert first and then add 1 to the positive number.
Although you CANT do this:

```
~num++; //Wont display the right value.
```

That will not work cause of [precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), postfix operators such as `num++` would be evaluated before ~ and the reason prefix `++num` wouldnt work even though it is on the same precedence as bitwise NOT(~), is cause it is evaluated from right to left. I did try to swap them around but it seems that prefix is a little finicky compared to bitwise NOT.
The +1 will work because '+' has a higher precedence and will be evaluated later.

I found that solution to be rather fun and decided to expand on it as it was just thrown in there and post people looking at it were probably ignoring it. Although yes, it wont work with floats.

My hopes are that this post hasn't moved away from the original question. :/

Answer (score 2):

My minimal approach

**For converting negative number to positive & vice-versa**

```js
var num = -24;
num -= num*2;
console.log(num)
// result = 24
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **~** operator that logically converts the number to negative and adds 1 to the negative:

```js
var x = 3;
x = (~x + 1);
console.log(x)
// result = -3
```

Answer (score 1):

I know another way to do it. This technique works negative to positive & Vice Versa

```
var x = -24;
var result = x * -1;
```

**Vice Versa:**

```
var x = 58;
var result = x * -1;
```

**LIVE CODE:**

```js
// NEGATIVE TO POSITIVE: ******************************************
var x = -24;
var result = x * -1;
console.log(result);

// VICE VERSA: ****************************************************
var x = 58;
var result = x * -1;
console.log(result);

// FLOATING POINTS: ***********************************************
var x = 42.8;
var result = x * -1;
console.log(result);

// FLOATING POINTS VICE VERSA: ************************************
var x = -76.8;
var result = x * -1;
console.log(result);
```

Comment: That does not answer the question. dave asks for a function that changes value *negative to positive* and *positive to positive*.

Comment: His question says "Is there a math function in JavaScript that converts numbers to positive value?" He does not mention positive to positive. He only mentions negative to positive. Why would you want to convert positive to positive. The value would be the same.

Comment: You can ask for clarification in a comment below the question. Anyway, there is an accepted answer that is the correct one. You can read it again and see that there's a built-in function that ... converts positive to positive.

Answer (score 0):

For a functional programming Ramda has a nice method for this. The same method works going from positive to negative and vice versa.

https://ramdajs.com/docs/#negate