# Negative values should not show in text box

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

[Plunker](https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/5664/)

I have a text field and I don't want to should negative values in the text box.If the value is negative then I simply leave that text box.

I have a directive, it is not allowing negative values but when data is coming from backend it is displaying the negative values.

```
app.directive('numbersOnly', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
            function fromUser(text) {
                if (text) {
                    var transformedInput = text.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');

                    if (transformedInput !== text) {
                        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                        ngModelCtrl.$render();
                    }
                    return transformedInput;
                }
                return undefined;
            }            
            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(fromUser);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Use Math.abs(x). < https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652104/convert-a-negative-number-to-a-positive-one-in-javascript >

Answer (score 0):

Use Math.abs(x)

```
function LoginController($scope) {
    $scope.number = Math.abs(-10);
      $scope.number1 =  Math.abs(-20);
        $scope.number2 =  Math.abs(-30);
}
```

[Ref Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652104/convert-a-negative-number-to-a-positive-one-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

this is meeting your requirement ?

https://jsfiddle.net/kjtqLvch/

html:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="LoginController">
<input ng-model="number" ng-change="validate()" type="number" ng-init="validate()"></input>

    <input ng-model="number1"></input>
    <input ng-model="number2"></input>
    <input type="submit" ng-click="login()" value="Login"></input>
</div>
```

js:

```
function LoginController($scope) {
    $scope.number = -10;
      $scope.number1 = -20;
        $scope.number2 = -30;
        $scope.validate = function(){
            $scope.number>=0?
          $scope.number = $scope.number:
          $scope.number=0;
        }
}
```

Comment: In this I am able to see the negative values, But when negative value comes then I don't want to show any value there, Just I want to leave that text box, but ng-model should contain negative value

Comment: so you want to show it empty if the model is negative and you want o leave model as it is?
if this is the case then you have to use a custom filter