# change all minus values to positive values in array using javascript

Tags: javascript

How to change all negative values to positive values in an `array` using javascript, for example:

```
const arry = [-2.5699, -1.4589, -3.2447, -6.9789 ,-9.213568];
```

My result should be `[2.56, 1.45, 3.24, 6.97, 9.21]`

How is it possible in javascript?

I tried with `Math.abs` but I am getting `NaN`

Comment: You want to round down like that?

Comment: How to convert negative numbers to positives has been answered in this duplicate [**Convert a negative number to a positive one in JavaScript**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652104/convert-a-negative-number-to-a-positive-one-in-javascript) and How to truncate decimals without rounding has been answered in this duplicate [**Truncate number to two decimal places without rounding**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187146/truncate-number-to-two-decimal-places-without-rounding)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Math.abs` to return the absolute value of a number.

```js
const arry = [-2.5699, -1.4589, -3.2447, -6.9789, -9.213568];

const arry2 = arry.map( v => Math.floor( Math.abs(v) * 100) / 100 );

console.log(arry2);
```

Answer (score 5):

> I tried with Math.abs but I getting NAN

Use `map`

```
var arry = [-2.5699, -1.4589, -3.2447, -6.9789 ,-9.213568];
arry = arry.map( s => Math.abs(s));
```

**Demo**

```js
var arry = [-2.5699, -1.4589, -3.2447, -6.9789, -9.213568];
arry = arry.map(s => Math.abs(s));
console.log(arry);
```

**Edit**

In short (as @pwolaq suggested)

```
arry = arry.map(Math.abs)
```

**Edit 2**

Missed the rounding off part

```
var fnRound = (s) => +String(s).match(/\d+\.?\d{0,2}/)[0];

var arry = [-2.5699, -1.4589, -3.2447, -6.9789, -9.213568];
arry = arry.map(Math.abs).map( fnRound );
```

**Demo**

```js
var fnRound = (s) => +String(s).match(/\d+\.?\d{0,2}/)[0];

var arry = [-2.5699, -1.4589, -3.2447, -6.9789, -9.213568];
arry = arry.map(Math.abs).map( fnRound ); 
console.log(arry);
```

**Regex Explanation** `/\d+\.?\d{0,2}/`

- `\d+` to match digits before decimal
- .? to match a decimal `0` or `1` times.
- `\d{0,2}` to match 2 digits after decimal.

Comment: @gurvinder372 thank u for replay if my value in positive also it will work

Comment: Linked to several duplicates answering all this already with lots of variations, including this/similar regex, etc..

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to **truncate** your numbers, not **round** them, then following code will work:

```
var arry = [-2.5699, -1.4589, -3.2447, -6.9789 ,-9.213568];
arry = arry.map(value => Math.floor(Math.abs(value) * 100)/100);
```