# How to return a positive value

Tags: javascript, return-value

I am just a few weeks into Javascript and would love your help in this issue.

What I have now is:

A:

```js
const howManyYears = (year) => {
 let dateToday = new Date();
 let thisYear = dateToday.getFullYear();

 const yearDifference = year - thisYear;
```

B:

```js
if (yearDifference > 0) {
 return 'You will graduate in ' + yearDifference + ' more years';
} else if (yearDifference < 0) {
 return 'She graduated ' + yearDifference + 'years before you';
}
```

How can I get positive value for `yearDifference` so it can fit the sentence structure at B?

Comment: `Math.abs(yearDifference)`

Comment: `'She graduated ' + (-yearDifference )` ? Since it's a negative number, it will necessarily come out positive...

Comment: Math.abs(yearDifference) and be sure year and thisYear variable is int type

Comment: Or just multiply with -1

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
Math.abs(yearDifference)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Use the conditional operator.

```
const yearDifferenceAbs = yearDifference > 0
    ? yearDifference
    : yearDifference * -1;
```

Then use `yearDifferenceAbs` in your sentences.

### Why

It's more explicit because you know exactly what the logic is.

It's also faster than `Math.abs()`, according to [this source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49571970/14116367).