# Converting a value from negative to positive or positive to negative in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I saw [this answer on how to convert a negative number to positive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781568/how-to-change-a-negative-number-to-positive), but have a slightly different situation: I’m doing some coding in Apache Cordova and getting accelerometer data I need to flip.

So when the accelerometer returns an X axis value of `-5` I need to convert it to `5` and the opposite as well; if the X axis value is `5` the new X axis value should be `-5`.

I understand how to do `-Math.abs()` and such, but how can I accommodate a situation like this in my code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do a simple math at this context, no need of `Math.abs`,

```
x_value = x_value * -1;
```

Or you can negate the value like,

```
x_value = -(x_value);
```

While negating, there is a chance to get `-0`, But we don't need to worry about it, since `-0 == 0`. [Abstract equality comparison algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) is telling so in *Step 1* - *c* - *vi*.

Comment: @JakeGould Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 4):

You can multiply any number by **-1** to get its [opposite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_inverse).

*Example:*

```
 5 * -1 = -5  
-5 * -1 =  5
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need Math.abs?

```
x_value = -1 * x_value;
```

works for every scenario I can envision.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use the [multiplication assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Multiplication_assignment) with `-1`.

> The multiplication assignment operator multiplies a variable by the value of the right operand and assigns the result to the variable. See the [multiplication operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Multiplication) for more details.

```
value *= -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, my solution is to create a ternary like this to see if the `x_value` is greater than 0 or not and act accordingly:

```
x_value = x_value > 0 ? -Math.abs(x_value) : Math.abs(x_value);
```